# Python Tools for Visual Studio and Unit Tests (PTVS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

Hopefully someone can give me a hand/few pointers.

So I am currently working on some python scripts and wanted to get some tests written.

My environment is as follows:
MS Visual Studio Community 2015, v.14 Update 3
PTVS v.2.2.4 (2.2.40623.00-14.0)
Python 3.5 64-bit Environment

I have some demo tests written in a test class, which have been appearing and disappearing in test explorer under their own will. Currently, I have none showing in Test Explorer, as per the screenshot below...

[image: Screenshot]
Several other people seem to be having issues, and the reasons vary from the test settings processor architecture selected, through to clearing the files in the temp folder etc.

I have been pulling out my hair for a few days now, and am looking for your help, cos i'm now bald.

I've tried removing PTVS and reinstalling, updating to latest, changing the test environment, adding and removing Nunit, incase that was conflicting, etc etc etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just managed to get this error message to appear, but I do not think it's correct:

[image: Test Error Msg]

OK, so another update:

I decided that I would download VS CE 2013, and then install PTVS 2.2.3.

I opened the solution there, and the tests loaded instantly, and ran first time...

[image]

I know that is not a solution to the problem, but at least I can now run my tests and continue working.

Kindest Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that PTVS does not fully work with VS2015 Community Edition.

You can run your scripts etc, but it does not integrate with the test explorer properly.

You will need to download VS2013 CE, and PTVS 2.2.2. Then you can run the test explorer and click run all, which will find all your tests, and run properly. Hope this helps someone, as I spent days trying to get VS2015 and PTVS 2.2.4 working with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem with VS2017.